# How can i creat tests for ArrayList in BlueJ?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I have ArrayList and I want to create test, where i find if every part of the list is there.

I use this test method:

```
@Test
public void testZnamky() {
    SeznamZnamek seznamZn1 = new SeznamZnamek();
    Znamka znamka1 = new Znamka("A", 1);
    Znamka znamka2 = new Znamka("B", 2);
    seznamZn1.VlozZnamku(znamka1);
    seznamZn1.VlozZnamku(znamka2);
    assertEquals(xxxxxxxx, seznamZn1.znamky());
}
```

`seznamZn1.znamky()` works fine, but in the test I don't know what I have to write to the place, where are xxxxxxxx..

Thanks

Comment: What should `seznamZn1.znamky()` return?

Comment: private List<Znamka> seznamZnamek = new ArrayList<>();


public Collection<Znamka> znamky() {
        return seznamZnamek;
    }

Comment: everythink works fine, but I dont know, how to test it

Comment: Try describing in English what the result should be when you call `seznamZn1.znamky()` in the test case you provide above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the other ArrayList there.

Comment: And can you write in english please?

Comment: private List<Znamka> seznamZnamek = new ArrayList<>();